# Addition of integers followed by addition string followed by more integers

Tags: javascript, html

Why in Javascript/HTML does addition of integers followed by the addition of a string followed by the addition of more integers result in the integers being added right away correctly but after the string they are treated essentially as a string?

Ex.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var y = 5 + 5 + 2 + "3" + 1 + 2;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<br>" + y + "<br>"
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Running this returns    12312, which is the addition of 5+5+2 and the string "3" but then concatenates 1 and 2 rather than adding...why is this?

Comment: `console.log(typeof (2 + "3"))` is `string`, a string + 1 is concatenation not addition

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculations are performed left to right. The result after 5+5+2 is an integer; the result 
after 5 + 5 + 2 + "3" is a string. Adding a string to an integer always results in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Once you add a string to an integer, the whole thing will remain a string so you just concatenate some additional numbers after that. 
You could use some brackets around the numbers to add them up before concatenating them.